# Passing a parameter to a WITH clause query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, with-clause

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass one or more parameters to a WITH clause query; in a very simple way, doing something like this (taht, obviously, is not working!):

```
with qq(a) as (
  select a+1 as increment 
    from dual
)
select qq.increment 
  from qq(10); -- should get 11
```

Of course, the use I'm going to do is much more complicated, since the with clause should be in a subquery, and the parameter I'd pass are values taken from the main query....details upon request... ;-)

Thanks for any hint

Comment: You cannot do this in Oracle. If you wish to do this why dont you use a paramterised cursor.

Comment: You are giving `WITH` a wrong meaning; you are trying to use it as a function, while it's more similar to a table; for example, `WITH T(A) as (select 1 from dual)` means something like 'considering a table `T` with a column `A`, given by `select 1 from dual`', ...

Comment: In 12c you _could_ create a function in the with clause, but given the fact that for a set returning function you also need to create a TYPE in Oracle I don't see a way to do something like that in a single query.

Comment: @Aleksej ... that was an oversimplified example; what I need is actually a table, made of several records generated in a subquery through a recursive query, joined with the master query; so far, number and values of the generated records would vary according to the values of some specific fields of the current record....
I hope this is clear enough...

Comment: Your example is too simplified. It is redundant to use `with` clause this way. Could you please add to the question a sample data and what do you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

OK.....here's the whole deal:

```
select appu.* from 
(<quite a complex query here>) appu
where not exists 
      (select 1 
             from dual 
             where appu.ORA_APP IN 
                   (select slot from 
                      (select distinct slots.inizio,slots.fine from 
                            (
                             with 
                             params as (select 1900 fine from dual)
                             --params as (select app.ora_fine_attivita fine 
                             -- where app.cod_agenda = appu.AGE
                             -- and app.ora_fine_attivita = appu.fine_fascia
                             --and app.data_appuntamento = appu.dataapp
                             --)
                             , 
                             Intervals (inizio, EDM) as
                             ( select 1700, 20 from dual
                             union all
                             select inizio+EDM, EDM from Intervals join params on 
                             (inizio <= fine)
                             )
                             select * from Intervals join params on (inizio <= fine)
                       ) slots
                    ) slots
        where slots.slot <= slots.fine
      )
      order by 1,2,3;
```

Without going in too deep details, the where condition should remove those records where 'appu.ORA_APP' match one of the records that are supposed to be created in the (outer) 'slots' table. 
The constants used in the example are good for a subset of records (a single 'appu.AGE' value), that's why I should parametrize it, in order to use the commented 'params' table (to be replicated, then, in the 'Intervals' table.

I know thats not simple to analyze from scratch, but I tried to make it as clear as possible; feel free to ask for a numeric example if needed....
Thanks

Comment: You should move this back into your original post (the Question) - this is not an Answer, but a clarification of your question.

Comment: Try and you'll find out for sure! (It will, but try it yourself.)